# Load bearing or not?

Tags: load-bearing, renovation, closet

This closet didn’t seem to match the beam in the attic so I didn’t think it was load bearing. However it has this huge header pictured. Any advice on how to remove this closet or is it better not to mess with?

[image]

This is on the 2nd floor. Below is the kitchen and open space.

The floor is tiled so unable to see directly below. Previous owner did some renovations to this area but it’s not obvious what’s original or what changed.

There’s usually a header on an interior closet, but this header is larger than I’ve seen before.

Comment: Can you see what's below the floor?

Comment: Its normal to have a lintel above windows and doors so that there is "no sag", which would cause the doors and windows to jam.

Comment: This is on the 2nd floor. Below is the kitchen and open space. The floor is tiled so unable to see directly below. Previous owner did some renovations to this area but it’s not obvious what’s original or what changed. Usually yes there’s a header on an interior closet, but the header is larger than I’ve usually seen.

Comment: Open to keeping the left side wall of closet if adding a couple 2x4s to help support load will work and put me on the safer side if it may be load bearing

Comment: Look in the attic if any trusses or joists are resting on this header.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the attic space above this and annotate (draw afterwards, or simply lay something in the attic before you take the pic) to indicate which way this closet wall is aligned in relation to the joists in the attic? That will help indicate whether this is "most likely" load bearing or "we can't tell from a pic". It is unusual to use very large lumber like that for a non-load-bearing header, but if the framers happened to have some scraps laying around, it's faster to cut 2 pieces of 2x than to cut several little studs...

Comment: looks like it's thin/hollow, just used for laziness or sturdiness, depending on if you're a pessimist or optimist